# Flask not redirecting index page

Tags: python, flask

When I request GET "/" on the browser to get index page, the server returns a 404 response.

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def route_root():
    if session.get('logged_in'):
        return redirect(url_for('machines'))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

There are no sessions at the first time, so the Flask server redirects the login page.
But the browser receives a 404 page.

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Console log:

```
192.168.110.2 - - [27/Sep/2021 11:59:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

And I've tried the default source code that displays the console log,
but nothing displays on the console log.

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    print('call index function')
    return 'test'
```

What should I do?

Comment: did you define `login` function ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `login` and `machines` function like following:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET'])
def login():
    print('call login function')
    return 'test'

@app.route('/machines', methods=['GET'])
def machines():
    print('call machines function')
    return 'test'
```